# Node express return message with link

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've node program which in case of error needs to send error message ,
this works, however I want to add to the message also a link.

something like

```
Something went wrong and we cannot open your application.
Follow this tutorial to proceed.
```

And the **this tutorial** will be a link e.g. https://nodejs.org/en/about/

How can I do that?

```
...
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong and we cannot open your application.Follow <a href="https://nodejs.org/en/about/">this</a> tutorial to proceed.'
        )
    }
```

And I send the data via express like `res.send`

```
app.get('/', async function (req, res) {

    try {
        const url = await invokeApp()

    } catch (e) {
        res.send(e.message)
    }

})
```

**update**

while trying the suggestion below I able to get the link but the messege order was changed, any idea how to fix it ?

```
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong and we cannot open your application.Follow <a href="https://nodejs.org/en/about/">this</a> tutorial to proceed.'
        )
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```js
...
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong and we cannot open your application. Follow <a href="https://nodejs.org/en/about/">this</a> tutorial to proceed.')
    }
```

You can use `res.send` with html string -- i.e `res.send('<p> html </p>')` - and deal with on the other side.

Comment: Thanks, please see my update. the link now working however all the message order was changed, any idea?

Comment: @BenoOdr Try to encapsulate everything to a valid html tag instead of just the link. Something like `'<p>Something went wrong and we cannot open your application.Follow <a href="https://nodejs.org/en/about/">this</a> tutorial to proceed.</p>'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
res.json({ err : e.message , link : "error/url"})
```

and if error comes you could acces url from this object and display the link in front end.

Comment: I saw that however how could I send the message with link ?

Comment: in above code  u r sending error message as well as error link. u can show it together in frontend taking the values from this object

Comment: but how should I put the link in the `this` word ?

Comment: in frontend you put this word in an anchor tag and give its href to this link which you get from the error response which uve sent

Comment: could you provide example how to do it ?

Comment: catch (e) {
        throw new Error(`Something went wrong , follow <a  href=${e.link}>this</a> tutorial to proceed`)
    }